# How to use sec:[something] in a thymeleaf expression?

Tags: spring-security, thymeleaf

I know how to use `sec:authentication="name"` and `sec:authorize="hasAnyRole(...)"` and produce a result on their own HTML tag, but now I want to use them in an expression such as:

```
th:if="${hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN') and someotherboolexpression}"
```

Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using [`thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity`](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity) module, you can use Spring security's authorization expression inside `th:if` using the `#authorization` expression utility object.

```
<div th:if="${#authorization.expression('hasRole(''ROLE_ADMIN'')') and #authorization.expression('...') }">
    This will only be displayed if authenticated user has role ROLE_ADMIN.
</div>
```

In fact the dialects added by this new module use `sec` as the default prefix so you can use the `sec:authentication` and `sec:authorize` as if you are using the tag library.

```
<div sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
    This will only be displayed if authenticated user has role ROLE_ADMIN.
</div>

<div sec:authentication="name">
    The value of the "name" property of the authentication object should appear here.
</div>
```

All you have to do is to add the dialect to your template engine configuration

```
<bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.SpringTemplateEngine">
    ...
    <property name="additionalDialects">
        <set>
            <!-- Note the package would change to 'springsecurity3' if you are using that version -->
            <bean class="org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity4.dialect.SpringSecurityDialect"/>
        </set>
    </property>
    ...
</bean>
```

Comment: @Bnrdo How to do the same using a java class?