# Sending security parameter in Script tag with Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm trying to send a parameter in the script tag like this:

```
<script th:src="@{/js/myScript.js(arg0=${value})}"></script>
```

Where value is the result for: **hasAuthority('USER')**

So, I tried this:

```
<script th:src="@{/js/myScript.js(arg0=${hasAuthority('USER')})}"></script>
```

But this doesn't work:

```
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "hasAuthority('USER')" (template: "groups" - line 61, col 9)

Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E: Method call: Method hasAuthority(java.lang.String) cannot be found on org.thymeleaf.spring4.expression.SPELContextMapWrapper type
```

I've used this function before for showing divs without problems:

```
<li sec:authorize="${hasAuthority('ADMIN')}">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
<script sec:authorize="${hasAuthority('USER')}" th:src="@{/js/myScript.js(arg0=ADD_VALUE_HERE)}"></script>
```

This will only load this particular js if you have the right authority. For your case, just change the value of the js argument for whatever you need.

Comment: My idea is to send true/false using hasAuthority. Is that possible?

Comment: Sadly no, but can achieve something very similar this using Thymeleaf extras from Spring Security. This question could help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35133062/how-to-use-secsomething-in-a-thymeleaf-expression

Comment: Should you need more help with Thymeleaf Spring Security Extras, please let me know.